# Web API - load resources only once in Business Layer

Tags: c#, .net, xml, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api

In my n-Layered application `Web API` is calling the `Business Layer`(BL) which is a class library project. In the BL I have a folder with several `XML templates`. For every request that comes to the Web API an instance of BL's class is created which in turn reads one or more XML templates and do some tasks.
I want to know - is there any way that the XML Templates are loaded/parsed only once so that the subsequent requests read the template from memory ?
I do not wish to move the templates to API layer.

Comment: try caching the templates

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways by which you can achieve this:

1. Save XML data in cache on your webserver and use it later whenever required.
2. You can also create a Static class and load XML content in it on Application Start event and can use it.
3. Last but a bit complex, you can use any DI framework Unity/AutoFaq and can create Singleton objects of your XML data. (very close to point 2)

Comment: Thanks @Soviut for removing unnecessary chars

Comment: XMLs are present in Class Lib proj (BL) and there is no application_start over there.

Comment: Then you can write this code anywhere where you are currently reading XML and save it to some object by using any of above 3 technique. 

In the next calls you can check if it is already loaded, if no, read the XML otherwise move ahead.